# Trivial Algebra with a vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, vectors, physics, classical-mechanics

I'm currently working on a standard two-body physics problem and am stuck on what I'm assuming is trivial algebra.

For the following expression

$$ L = \frac{1}{2} a\mathbf {\dot r_1}^2 + \frac{1}{2}b\mathbf {\dot r_2}^2 -U(r) \tag{1}\label{1}$$

Let

$$
\left\{
\begin{aligned} 
\mathbf r_1 = \frac{b \  \mathbf r}{a+b}\\
\mathbf r_2 = \frac{-a \  \mathbf r}{a+b}
\end{aligned} 
\right. 
$$

Given the three equations, I need to prove the following relation as a part of $\eqref{1}$.

$$ \frac{1}{2} a \bigg(\frac{b \ \mathbf {\dot r} }{a+b} \bigg )^2 + \frac{1}{2} b \bigg(\frac{-a \ \mathbf {\dot r} }{a+b} \bigg )^2  = \frac{1}{2} \bigg ( \frac{ab}{a+b} \bigg ) \mathbf {\dot r}^2  \tag{2}\label{2} $$

My final equation for $L$ should be
$$ L =  \frac{1}{2} \bigg ( \frac{ab}{a+b} \bigg ) \mathbf {\dot r}^2 -U(r)$$

I've tried to distribute the square, but am left with an expression that does not reduce to the RHS of \eqref{2}. (Unless I'm missing something simple.) I believe there is some property with the vector that I'm not aware of that allows this to work.

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: What does it even mean to square a vector?

Comment: @DanielMcLaury Physics speak for dotting the vector with itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\frac{ab^2+ba^2}{(a+b)^2} = \frac{ab(b+a)}{(a+b)^2} = \frac{ab}{a+b}$$